# 24H time format not applied on other locations

Tags: desktop-environments, time

Though my time is set to 24H, the toolbar widget shows time in other locations on 12h not 24h.

The discrepancy with the location configuration is pretty clear in the screenshot below:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is most likely due to a known [bug][1]. Where did you set your time format?


  [1]: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1174261

Comment: I set the time format in the Ubuntu control panel (UI), not from the command line.

Comment: FTR this works perfectly fine on 12.04, so it's clearly a regression in 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

That is controlled by Regional Formats.

If the default for your locale is to show the time on 12h, then that's what you will see.

So if your your Regional Formats are set to **English (United States)**.

Selecting **English (Australia)** keeps all the American settings but shows the time on 24H.

New settings will apply on your next login.